# TypeScript: Access "this" inside a method of an anonymous class

Tags: typescript

In my code I'm creating a new anonymous class that is implementing an interface.

```
private service: CommandService;

this.command = new class implements Command {
  execute(id: string): Promise<Result> {
    const resultId: string = await this.service.getResultId();
    return await this.service.getResult(resultId);
  };
};
```

What would be the best way to access the service in this case? I'm thinking of either

- define `const _this = this` above the class.
- give the service to the `execute` function.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Edit:

I know that there's a wonderful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) here already, however, it doesn't explain how to access `this` within an anonymous class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Please see my edit.

Comment: The essence of the answers will be the same; set a variable to `this` outside the callback; pass the instance to the callback as the `thisArg` to `call` or `apply`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You never want to assign `this.` to a variable, that kind of breaks the whole point of using classes.  This should instead be 2 diffrent classes, and just pass the needed values into the "inner" class, like this

```js
import { Command, CommandService, Result } from 'foo';

class MyCommand implements Command {
    constructor(private readonly service: CommandService) { }
    async execute(id: string): Promise<Result> {
        const resultId: string = await this.service.getResultId();
        return await this.service.getResult(resultId);
    };
};

class ParentClass {
    private readonly service: CommandService;
    private readonly command = new MyCommand(this.service); 
}
```

Comment: "You never want to assign `this` to a variable, that kind of breaks the whole point of using classes."  Why?  Is that just your opinion or do you have some source that corroborates this?

Comment: For example, I'm not sure what's wrong with [either of these solutions](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wixfgd?file=index.ts) or how one or both is "breaking" classes.

Comment: @jcalz Wondering about the same thing.

Comment: Sure it can be done and it works, but it just seems overly complex.  Perhaps "breaking" was the wrong word choice, I apologize for that.  Ideally (to me anyway) you want a single class per file.  Define each class separately and then call new instances of them instead of creating entirely new classes.  `new MyCommand()` instead of `(new class implements Command { ... } )()` and then having to pass contexts around.